# Expansion of datetime command

Tags: expansion, datetime

For a project I'm working on, I am writing text from a LaTeX document to a simple PHP document to use on a poster. However, I've run into a problem which I'm unable to resolve;

I am using the datetime package to store dates, and I want to put a created date in the PHP file. However, I don't really seem to be understanding expansion in LaTeX as I cannot figure out how to do this.

The date is saved in a command as follows:

```
\newcommand\@@meetingDate{}

\newcommand\meetingDate[3]{
    \newdate{meeting}{#1}{#2}{#3}
    \iftoggle{dutch}{\renewcommand\@@meetingDate{\datedutch\displaydate{meeting}}}{
        \renewcommand\@@meetingDate{\usdate\displaydate{meeting}}}
}
```

The meetingDate is set such that it can be used on the actual file I am creating. I'm using the following code to write information to another file:

```
    %% Get date and location
    \newwrite\generalone
    \immediate\openout\generalone=data/generaldata.php
        \immediate\write\generalone{<table class="adjes">}
        \immediate\write\generalone{<tr>}
        \immediate\write\generalone{<th class="number"> Date: </th>}
        \immediate\write\generalone{<th class="comment"> \@@meetingDate </th>}
        \immediate\write\generalone{</tr>}
        \immediate\write\generalone{<tr>}
        \immediate\write\generalone{<th class="number"> Location: </th>}
        \immediate\write\generalone{<th class="comment"> \@@meetingLocation </th>}      
        \immediate\write\generalone{</tr>}
        \immediate\write\generalone{</table>}
    \closeout\generalone
```

Note, the meetingLocation macro is working fine as it needs no expansion.

I have searched a good portion on expansion, but am still not sure how to expand this command such that I can write it to a file.

Am I able to do this at all, and if so, how can it be achieved? Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome! Neither `\usdate` nor `\displaydate` can work as you hope, because the make assignments, which are not executed during `\write` operations.

Comment: @egreg that's exactly what I was stuck on. Do you know if there is any way to fully expand these such that the actual 'value' of these operations can be written to the file?

Comment: You should try with `datetime2`. But I find the support for languages very complicated.

Comment: I ended up just making a simple implementation of the part I was using of ```datetime``` package, just solved a big part of my problems.